# Access a widget from another widget in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Using traditional XML you can get the instance of a View using it's id or tag.

How is this possible in jetpack compose?

```
Card(elevation = 1.dp, shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp), color = Color.Transparent) {
      // TARGET is here
      Padding(padding = 8.dp) {
           Text(text = "Net stat", style = +themeTextStyle { h6 })
      }
}
Text(text = netStatusState.value)
HeightSpacer(height = 10.dp)
Divider()
HeightSpacer(height = 10.dp)
Card(elevation = 1.dp, shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp), color = Color.Transparent) {
     Padding(padding = 8.dp) {
           Clickable(onClick = {
                            // MODIFY (Remove, change element, update attr) the target
                     }) {
              Button(text = "Click me if you can")
           }
     }
}
```

Is it even needed such a feature, or it's **all done using the state**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Composables do not have IDs, and you generally shouldn't need to get an instance of a composable. It is helpful to think of Composable functions as print statements. Just like a println() function takes some data and writes it to the console, Composable functions take data and measure/layout/draw this data onto the screen.

If you change the data, and the data is in a class annotated with @Model, the Jetpack compose system will automatically call the appropriate functions again using the new state and your UI will be updated.